# Is console.log in JS a part of Web Api that browser provides

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning Web Apis. What confused me a bit is that if console.log is a part of Web Api that browser provides, if so, then why isn't it launched via callback queue, I mean, as far as I know JS at runtime sends off something that does not belong to it to Web Api to be launched. For example, dom, setTimeOut are web apis and browser does not launch it on its own but sends off to web api

Comment: What do you mean by "callback queue"?

Comment: @zero298, is it true that there are two types of web apis that browser provides which are synchronous and asynchronous for example fetch and settimeout are asynchronous and console.log is synchronous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are mixing up synchronous and asynchronous with Browser API functions and ECMAScript core.  JavaScript engines (like Rhino, node.js, etc.) can add in their own APIs in addition to the ECMA core functionality guarenteed in the spec.

These APIs can include functions that are synchronous and asynchronous.  For example, the `setTimeout` will use the event loop, `console.log()` will synchronously write to the browser's console (implementations vary between engines), `fetch` will call an asynchronous function that can be `await`ed.

These engines can add whatever they want to their JavaScript API, but these additional APIs are not required to be async/sync or even use the event loop.